# Foreach does not insert the key and value in array element

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

When I send an array and a value to this function, I'd like it to insert a new key (`id`) and its `$value` into the array, but it doesn't

```
function AddID($tab,$value){
    foreach($tab as $element){
        $element['id']=$value;
    }
    return $tab;
}
```

Could someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Edit :

Input :

```
$result1=$function1($search_string);
    $result_array1 = CreateArray($result1);
    $result_array1 = AddID($result_array1,"profile");
```

(CreateArray works fine it's mysql fetch array)

Output :

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=22)
      0 => string 'email@quipu.ducul' (length=17)
      'Email' => string 'email@quipu.ducul' (length=17)
      1 => string 'innov24' (length=7)
      'NickName' => string 'innov24' (length=7)
      2 => string 'TCA-Innov24' (length=11)
      'Company' => string 'TCA-Innov24' (length=11)
      3 => string 'hahaha' (length=6)
      'LastName' => string 'hahaha' (length=6)
      4 => string 'pouet' (length=5)
      'FirstName' => string 'pouet' (length=5)
      5 => string 'Antarctica' (length=10)
      'Country' => string 'Antarctica' (length=10)
      6 => string 'Dans mon igloo' (length=14)
      'City' => string 'Dans mon igloo' (length=14)
      7 => string 'Journalist' (length=10)
      'Name' => string 'Journalist' (length=10)
      8 => string '1' (length=1)
      'ID' => string '1' (length=1)
      9 => string '290' (length=3)
      'AqbPoints' => string '290' (length=3)
      10 => string 'AQ' (length=2)
      'count' => string 'AQ' (length=2)
```

Comment: Give an example input and output please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [pass by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) on the `$element`. The link to the documentation can explain it more clearly than I can, but here is a quote:

> You can pass a variable by reference to a function so the function can
>   modify the variable.

Your function should look like this:

```
function AddID($tab, $value){
    foreach($tab as &$element) { // Notice the &$element
        $element['id'] = $value;
    }

    return $tab;
}
```

Here is the code running: https://ideone.com/ax311G

If you do not want to pass by reference you will have to create a new array from the existing one:

```
function AddID($tab, $value){
    $newArray = array();
    foreach($tab as $element){
        $element['id'] = $value;
        $newArray[] = $element; // Adds to new array
    }
    return $newArray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm but the structure is looking a little bit different :
      10 => string 'AQ' (length=2)
      'count' => string 'AQ' (length=2)
      'id' => string 'profile' (length=7)

Comment: Yeah, I answered this before you edited it - Ayush Chaudhary's solution includes the actual keys. Still a bit confused as to what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($tab as $value) {
   $element[] = $value;
           ^^--shorthand for "array_push()"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify it by reference or by using the key for the array. You need to also make sure that each element of the `$tab` array is also an array, if not you can convert it to an array.

Here is the solution that takes care of both the cases:

```
function AddID($tab,$value){
    foreach($tab as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $tab[$k]['id']=$value;
        } else {
            $tab[$k] = array($v, 'id' => $value);
        }
    }
    return $tab;
}
```